# For regular expressions, do full-stops (.) in sets need escaping?

Tags: javascript

Consider `[-.\w]+`.

I know `[]` means either or. I know, usually, `.` means any character (except a newline).

My initial thought was isn't it pointless to group `.` next to `-` and `/w` since `.` means anything (apart from new line)?

However, does `.` here literally mean a full-stop (or period if you're American) because a lot of characters don't need escaping in sets? And `.` is one of them?

P.s. If you do know the answer, would you mind sharing with me the resource that led to you knowing the answer?

Comment: This [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/pOJexe/1) Will describe for you exactly what each expression does and why. [This One](https://regex101.com/r/pOJexe/2) Includes search strings

Comment: `[]` doesn't mean either-or. It means any of the characters inside the brackets.

Comment: That regexp means any sequence of letters, numbers, underscores, hyphens, and dots.

Comment: Either-or is `either|or`

Comment: Short answer: no. A dot inside square brackets is a dot.

Comment: The only characters that need escaping inside square brackets are hyphen (except at the beginning), close bracket (except at the beginning), and backslash.

Comment: @Barmar @Zak @RoboRobok Thanks all. If `.` literally just means any character except new-line, then why bother putting it next to `-` & `\w`? Surely `.` encompasses them? Unless I've misunderstood what `[]` does - I thought it meant: search for any (one) of the characters found here.

Comment: `.` has no special meaning inside square brackets.

Comment: So `[.]` means to match a literal dot.

Comment: That's why it doesn't need escaping.

Comment: I don't know why you removed the link in your question. That site explained what that regexp matches.

Comment: **Any word can be the name, hyphens and dots are allowed. In regular expressions that’s `[-.\w]+`.**

Comment: **`[-.]`** matches a single character in the list **`[-.]`** (case sensitive)

Comment: Okay, my take-away is that in `[]` `.` just means a a dot - not every character asides new line like it does outside `[]`.